# Google Eclipse plugin manual telling to skip security warning. What are the risks?

Tags: attack-prevention, google

I'm trying to install GWT plugin for Eclipse. [The Google manual](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4) 
says among other things

[image: screenshot]
Eclipse indeed shows that message during installation. The questions are:

1. What exactly does that message mean? Is there a possibility for an attacker to substitute downloaded files to do evil things with my computer?
2. Why would Google set things up in a non-properly-secure way, and ask developers to ignore security warning while working with its plugin? Such things erode the whole internet security concept. Theoretically speaking, after ignoring this warning maybe I should also ignore Firefox's message about "*wrong SSL gmail certificate*?"

Comment: Ummm, if you're getting *Wrong SSL Gmail certificate* something is definitely wrong there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104429/verify-unsigned-plugins-for-eclipse